# Bash - adding values in row based on column

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed, command-line-interface

The 2nd column in my csv file has duplicates. I want to add the associated values from column 1 based on those duplicates.

Example csv :

```
56,  cc=DK
49,  cc=US
34,  cc=GB
32,  cc=DE
32,  cc=NZ
31,  cc=DK
31,  cc=GB
31,  cc=GB
```

Example result :

```
96,  cc=GB # where 96 = 34+31+31
87,  cc=DK # where 87 = 56+31
32,  cc=DE
32,  cc=NZ
```

Comment: `awk -F, '{a[$2]+=$1}END{for(i in a)print a[i] FS i}' file`. Also you left US off the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use associative arrays in `awk`:

```
awk '{s[$2]+=$1}END{for(k in s)print s[k]", ",k}' inFile
```

Expanding on that for readability, and using `sum/key` rather than `s/k`:

```
{                                 # Do for each line.
    sum[$2] += $1                 # Add first field to accumulator,
                                  #   indexed by second field.
                                  #   initial value is zero.
}
END {                             # Do this bit when whole file processed.
    for (key in sum)              # For each key like cc=US:
        print sum[key] ", " key   # Output the sum and key.
}
```

Here's a sample run on my box:

```
pax$ echo;echo '56,  cc=DK
49,  cc=US
34,  cc=GB
32,  cc=DE
32,  cc=NZ
31,  cc=DK
31,  cc=GB
31,  cc=GB' | awk '{s[$2]+=$1}END{for(k in s)print s[k]", "k}'

32, cc=DE
96, cc=GB
32, cc=NZ
49, cc=US
87, cc=DK
```

This works despite the fact that the first column is of the form `999,` (note the comma at the end), simply because `awk`, when evaluating strings in a numeric context, uses only the prefix that is valid in that context. Hence `45xyzzy` would become `45` and, more importantly, `49,` becomes `49`.

Comment: You can also change the FS instead of gsub(which is pointless as you are changing one `,` and could just use sub,as is the $1 as it defaults to $0) as per my code in the comment on the question.

Comment: @JID, I did think of that but it turns out the gsub/sub isn't even needed, so I removed it.

Comment: Oh yeah, you could shave off 2 more characters as the `{}` after the `(k in s)` are not needed.

Comment: @JID: done, though I'm not convinced we should be "code-golfing" this :-)

Comment: Using your awk line as well as the one in the comment on my initial post worked for my case. Thx! I ended up using : awk '{s[$2]+=$1}END{for(k in s)print s[k]", ",k}' inFile | sort -rn

Answer (score 1):

Perl solution:

```
perl -ane '$h{ $F[1] } += $F[0] }{ print "$h{$_}\t$_\n" for keys %h' input.csv
```

Explanation:

- `-n` processes the input line by line
- `-a` splits the input line on whitespace into fields in the @F array
- the hash table %h records the sum for each key (2<sup>nd</sup> column). It just adds the value of the first column to it.
- `}{` (called "Eskimo greeting") separates what's executed for each line (`-n`) from the code to be run after the whole input was processed

Answer (score 0):

It's ok to use `awk` for such simple task, but if you have bunch of similar tasks and you may need to change it in the future it's easy to mess something up.

Since it's typical database problem, consider using `sqlite`.

You can:

1. add row names and remove extra white spaces:

   ```
   $ cat <(echo "num, name") originalInput.txt | tr -d ' ' > input.csv
   ```
2. import data to temporary sqlite db:

   ```
   $ sqlite3 --batch temp.db <<EOF!
   .mode csv
   .import input.csv input
   EOF!
   ```
3. select from db:

   ```
   $sqlite3 temp.db 'SELECT sum(num), name FROM input GROUP BY name'
   32|cc=DE
   87|cc=DK
   96|cc=GB
   32|cc=NZ
   49|cc=US
   ```

It is slightly bit more code and uses external `sqlite3` command, but it's significantly **less error prone** and more **flexible**. You can do easily join several csv files, use fancy sorting, and more.

Also, imagine yourself looking at the code six month later trying to understand quickly what it does.

Comment: Your last statement depends on how familiar you are with the language, it would take me far longer to work out what your code does than the awk above. Tbh this just seems like overkill.Not only do you have to install an external program(something everyone may not be able to do for one reason or another) You also have to edit the original data,create a db and then get output that is no longer in CSV format. If you wanted a more robust way than awk you could just use a csv parser.

Comment: @JID, "it's ok to use awk, here, but *consider* sqlite if you have bunch of similar tasks". I've seen hundreds of such magic awk/sed/perl/*sh scripts in production and in many cases it was not right tool for the job. BTW, csv parser will not do aggregation for you.

Comment: I've also seen lots of `magic awk/sed/perl/*sh scripts` and if they have not been written terribly and you have a basic understanding of the language then you would have no trouble instantly understanding what is being done.Also I meant a csv parser in python or perl,reading it back i probably should have been more clear.